# Run IAR Program without Debugging

Tags: stm32, iar

I'm having a simple problem with IAR Embedded Workbench, programming an STM32 using an ST-LINK/V2 programmer. I'm trying to run a program that temporarily switches off the JTAG pins, so I can't run it all the way through in debug mode. What I would like to do is load and run the program (*without* debugging), then connect the debugger to the running program to check a few values and make sure it actually ran.

I can't figure out how to do either of these steps with IAR. I've tried doing a "Download active application" followed by a "Debug without Downloading," but either the program didn't start running or when the debugger connected it reset the program. When I try to use the "Attach to Running Target" option, I get an error message saying "The debugging session could not be started."

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: This question is not too bad. It deals with usage of an IDE s/w, whose major users are EEs. Voting to leave open.

Comment: No idea how to solve the problem under IAR, but with the open source stlink tool on github it's trivial to connect GDB over SWD to an already running target - but not very informative unless you have the .elf and debug symbols, which would probably require rebuilding your project with a GCC based toolchain.

Answer (score -1):

Old topic, no answer. For anyone who comes here, the solution is explained by IAR at [THIS](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/debugger/application-does-not-run-stand-alone/) link.

Comment: Stack exchange sites require that answers have stand-alone value, not simply be links to something external.

Comment: It will help people out anyways, specially because this question is kind of the first result popping out on google.